# Is there any Example of PHP user to user chat on sockets?

Tags: php, sockets, chat

Is there any Example of PHP user to user chat on sockets?

Comment: You want user-to-user code (client side), but you only want to see server-side logic (server side), but you don't want back-end code (server side). This is the most convoluted question I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "user to user" chats on the Web. Web-based chats all pass through a webserver, as there's no practical foolproof way to get two client browsers to open up a direct communications link between the two.

If you're dealing with web-based communications, better accept that all communications are client <-> server, not client <-> client.

That being said, you *can* have Flash open up links to other servers, using [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html), but that still requires server involvement.